# using an .xsd file in a validation method

Tags: c#, xsd

I have created a class in order to validate some XML. Within that class I have a validation method.  I also have a .xsd file which contains my XML schema.  I've been told that to use this file I must "Load the xsd file into a string"

How do you load an xsd file into a string?

Comment: So you have separate XML and XSD files and you want to use the XSD to validate the XML?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, my xml data will be pulled from a server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy to read the entire file into a string:

```
string schema;
using(StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path)
{
    schema = file.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Hope this helps you in your quest.

Answer (score 5):

Without more context, I have no idea what `Load the xsd file into a string` actually means, but there are far simpler methods to validate an XML.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var set = new XmlSchemaSet();

using (var stream = new StreamReader(xsdPath))
{
    // the null here is a validation call back for the XSD itself, unless you 
    //  specifically want to handle XSD validation errors, I just pass a null and let 
    //  an exception get thrown as there usually isn't much you can do with an error in 
    //  the XSD itself
    set.Add(XmlSchema.Read(stream, null));                
}

xDoc.Validate(set, ValidationCallBack);
```

Then you just need a method called `ValidationCallBack` in your class to be your handler for any validation failures (you can name it whatever you want, but delegate parameter the `Validate()` method above has to reference this method):

```
public void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    // do something with any errors
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try with this code

```
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.Schemas.Add("....", "youXsd.xsd");
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(YourSettingsValidationEventHandler);

        XmlReader books = XmlReader.Create("YouFile.xml", settings);

        while (books.Read()) { }


       //Your validation
       static void YourSettingsValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
       {

       }
```

2 If you want just load you can use StreamReader and ReadToEnd